# How to clear up this closure reference

Tags: javascript

For this code:

```
    var myObj = {
    callMeMaybe: function () {
        var myRef = this;
        var val = setTimeout(function () { 
            console.log('Time is running out!'); 
            myRef.callMeMaybe();
        }, 1000);
    }
};

myObj.callMeMaybe();
myObj = null;
```

if we call myObj.callMeMaybe() and then call myObj = null.
We still can't cancel the call to callMeMaybe(); Anyway to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried clearTimeout? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to `window.clearTimeout` on `val`.

```
    var myObj = {
    callMeMaybe: function () {
        var myRef = this;
        this.val = setTimeout(function () { // made val visible outside
            console.log('Time is running out!'); 
            myRef.callMeMaybe();
        }, 1000);
    }
};

myObj.callMeMaybe();

window.clearTimeout( myObj.val );
myObj = null;
```

Comment: This causes the entire `setTimeout` to be cancelled, which is not what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

The clearTimeout() method clears a timer set with the setTimeout() method.
The ID value returned by setTimeout() is used as the parameter for the clearTimeout() method.

```
clearTimeout(id_of_settimeout);
```

and the **Number.MAX_VALUE** is 1.7976931348623157e+308VALUE

I think this question can be done by clearTimeout loop 1.7976931348623157e+308VALUE times.

Does it take a long time?

Or you can get max id_of_settimeout by

```
max_id_of_settimeout = setTimeout(null,0);
```

Then loop back to **zero**

```
for (var i = max_id_of_settimeout;i>=0;i--){clearTimeout(i);}
```

Just my opinion.

Comment: because I think there's no way to **cancel the set timer** except clear all of them.

Answer (score -1):

Overwrite the `callMeMaybe` property with a new function, or `null` if you don't mind the TypeError.

```
myObj.callMeMaybe();
myObj.callMeMaybe = function(){};
```

Now when the asynchronous call is made from the `setTimeout`, it will invoke the empty function.

---

If you don't want to overwrite the function, then just set a flag on the object.

```
var myObj = {
    callMeMaybe: function () {
        var myRef = this;
        var val = setTimeout(function () { 
            console.log('Time is running out!'); 
            if (!myRef.prevent)
                myRef.callMeMaybe();
        }, 1000);
    }
};

myObj.callMeMaybe();
myObj.prevent = true; // will prevent the .callMeMaybe() in the setTimeout
```

---

But to be clear, you *can not clear* the closure reference itself. Objects are reference types, and JavaScript is pass by value.

This means when you do this:

```
var myRef = this;
```

...you've made a copy of the object reference. Because `myRef` is a local variable, it can't be touched from the outside. Best you can do is manipulate the object that is referenced, or make the `myRef` variable available to the outer scope.

...and ignore the down-voters. They don't understand how JavaScript works.

Comment: This won't work because `setTimeout` has already been called so the function passed to it has already been created.

Comment: @PaulS.: That's not correct. The `setTimeout` callback is invoking the `callMeMaybe` from the object reference, which will have its `callMeMaybe` property overwritten.

Comment: Look at the question again, `setTimeout` is not using `callMeMaybe` until after the log has been done so code will still execute.

Comment: @PaulS.: I know it's not. All you need to do is test the code to see that it works. The `callMeMaybe` is invoked from `myObj`, which means `this === myObj`. Then a reference is made in the function, so `myRef === myObj`. So when we overwrite the function on `myObj`, we're overwriting the function on `myRef`, and the code in the `setTimeout` will call the new function.

Comment: ...There's no indication in the question that the `console.log` shouldn't be invoked. He's only asking how to cancel the `callMeMaybe` itself.

Comment: The recursive nature made me think he didn't want anything more to happen as soon as the object was destroyed, but as the question was `we still can't cancel the call to callMeMaybe()` and not how to cancel the queued invocation, you may be correct, +1. It depends if they want any code in the `setTimeout`s callback other than the call to happen a last time after the object is destroyed.